# Метки «Jade» и «Pug»

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, переименование-метки, замена-меток

Препроцессор HTML [jade](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade) теперь называется [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html#project-rename). В связи с этим предлагаю сделать метку [pug](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pug) основной, [jade](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade) её синонимом.

Есть другой JADE — [Java Agent DEvelopment framework](http://jade.tilab.com/) — но по нему вопросов я не нашёл, поэтому полагаю, что занимать метку [jade](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade) для вопросов, которые неизвестно, будут ли ещё на сайте, неправильно. Если они появятся, предложил бы использовать метку [agents-jade](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agents-jade), как на [английском Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agents-jade). Другие же «Pug», связанные с программированием, не нагугливаются.

Вариант — пусть в новых, заданных после переименования препроцессора, вопросах используется [pug](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pug), а в старых остаётся [jade](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade). Причины:

1. Pug — это уже обновлённый Jade. Всё-таки Pug и Jade это немного разные вещи, и метки должны быть разными.
2. Раньше задавали вопросы именно по Jade, а не Pug.

В таком случае в краткое описание метки [jade](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade) предлагаю добавить что-то вроде: «Для вопросов о Pug, пожалуйста, используйте метку Pug».

Comment: Скоро фронтендерам не будет хватать слов для называния их новых, самых лучших, совершенно незаменимых библиотек.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а вы не слышали, чем вызвано переименование Jade? Правообладатели возмутились, что это их торговая марка, и потребовали переназваться. Так что слов уже не хватает :D

Comment: @NickVolynkin А можете всё-таки добавить синоним, так как даже на enSO — это синонимы?